# How to logout facebook - using code in rails application (Ruby on Rails Omniauth)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, omniauth

I tried to add more than one twitter and facebook accounts from my page via omniauth in rails.

Twitter working fine using `force_login` parameter.

But, facebook not supporting this.

i can add only one facebook account using `/auth/facebook`. After i tried to add new facebook account using `/auth/facebook` path then it returns to my home page only.

If i browse www.facebook.com in same browser then the login page not appearing. The lastly added facebook account page is opening.

when i logout from facebook in browser then i tried `/auth/facebook` path. its working fine.

So,
need to logout already opened facebook accounts in browser tabs, before i hit add facebook link in my page.

Can anyone help?
thanks.

Comment: watch this screencast it has the soultion > http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by deafult, you cannot log in multiple facebook account within one browser unless you have a method to trigger browser(like private browsing-mozilla, incognito Window-chrome ) to let your user sign in. websites uses cookies to track their status.

however, facebook do provide auth_type=reauthenticate.
which the doc is here.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-re-auth/

Any correct me if im wrong.

Comment: thank you. but in my application multiple users can login using facebook account. already added facebook cookies not allowing me to open new facebook login page. For example think browsing center. there multiple persons can possible to use single browser. think that condition.